# Cubic root of the negative number on python

Tags: python, math

Can someone help me to find a solution on how to calculate a cubic root of the negative number using python?

```
>>> math.pow(-3, float(1)/3)
nan
```

it does not work. Cubic root of the negative number is negative number. Any solutions?

Comment: As a side note: `float(1)` is more conveniently written as "1.".  Or you can use `from __future__ import division` and stop worrying about integer division (1/3 returns 0.3333...).

Comment: If you only want the real cube root, and ignore the complex cube roots, please say so in your question.

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no floating-point number that represents 1/3 exactly, so using mathematical functions like `math.pow()` there's no way to specify the cube root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use:

```
-math.pow(3, float(1)/3)
```

Or more generally:

```
if x > 0:
    return math.pow(x, float(1)/3)
elif x < 0:
    return -math.pow(abs(x), float(1)/3)
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Even more generally, you could make the < 0 condition instead be "x%2 == 1" and then define it instead as a function that could take a value N for the root instead of hard-coding 3.

Comment: just a note, if you're hard-coding `1/3` you don't need a special case for zero.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a special case for zero period, regardless of what the power is.

Comment: -1 for not using `math.pow(...) if x... else...`, and also for handling `x==0` as a separate case (math.pow(0, 1./3) is 0).

Comment: @SilentGhost `math.pow(0, -2)` raises an exception, which is much more appropriate than returning 0.  I do agree with you, Dav!

Comment: @Dav: I agree that the special case is unnecessary, but it felt a bit daft to me to call math.pow() in order to return a constant.  Admittedly, the same could be said for any value, but I was working on the assumption that the power may need to be changed to work with any odd reciprocal.

Answer (score 20):

A simple use of [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), is sufficient  to show that the cube root of a value, regardless of sign, is a multi-valued function. That means, for any input value, there will be three solutions. Most of the solutions presented to far only return the principle root. A solution that returns all valid roots, and explicitly tests for non-complex special cases, is shown below.

```
import numpy
import math
def cuberoot( z ):
    z = complex(z)
    x = z.real
    y = z.imag
    mag = abs(z)
    arg = math.atan2(y,x)
    return [ mag**(1./3) * numpy.exp( 1j*(arg+2*n*math.pi)/3 ) for n in range(1,4) ]
```

**Edit:** As requested, in cases where it is inappropriate to have dependency on numpy, the following code does the same thing.

```
def cuberoot( z ):
    z = complex(z) 
    x = z.real
    y = z.imag
    mag = abs(z)
    arg = math.atan2(y,x)
    resMag = mag**(1./3)
    resArg = [ (arg+2*math.pi*n)/3. for n in range(1,4) ]
    return [  resMag*(math.cos(a) + math.sin(a)*1j) for a in resArg ]
```

Comment: `arg` shouldn't be divided by `3`: `numpy.exp( 1j*(arg+2*n*math.pi/3) )`.
You could also use `math.cos+1j*math.sin` if you want to get rid of the dependency on numpy.

Comment: I did recall correctly from my math class.  So the currently accepted answer is, then, incomplete.

Comment: @MizardX - the division by three is required, it forms the denominator of the argument. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications

Answer (score 13):

```
math.pow(abs(x),float(1)/3) * (1,-1)[x<0]
```

Comment: "(1,-1)[x<0]" is an expression that makes me love and hate python at the same time ;-)

Comment: haha, I know exactly what you mean, but I wanted to see if I could get  this into one line.

Comment: What about python2.5 and later style `* (1 if x > 0 else -1)`

Comment: Oh, golf, is it?  You're 3 over par:  "math.pow(abs(x),y)*cmp(x,0)"

Comment: I guess that should be "math.pow(abs(x),1./3)*cmp(x,0)", since x<0 y=1/2 would be screwy.

Answer (score 10):

Taking the earlier answers and making it into a one-liner:

```
import math
def cubic_root(x):
    return math.copysign(math.pow(abs(x), 1.0/3.0), x)
```

Comment: why are you converting `x` to `float`?

Comment: +1 for copysign (neat new 2.6 function!-) but there's indeed no need for those float() calls.

Comment: I was confused by the copysign documentation and thought the parameter had to be a float.  However, integers work (I just tested it) so there's no need for the cast.  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the complete (all n roots) and more general (any sign, any power) solution using:

```
import cmath

x, t = -3., 3  # x**(1/t)

a = cmath.exp((1./t)*cmath.log(x))
p = cmath.exp(1j*2*cmath.pi*(1./t))

r = [a*(p**i) for i in range(t)]
```

Explanation:
a is using the equation x<sup>u</sup> = exp(u*log(x)).  This solution will then be one of the roots, and to get the others, rotate it in the complex plane by a (full rotation)/t.

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap the `libm` library that offers a `cbrt` (cube root) function:

```
from ctypes import *
libm = cdll.LoadLibrary('libm.so.6')
libm.cbrt.restype = c_double
libm.cbrt.argtypes = [c_double]
libm.cbrt(-8.0)
```

gives the expected

```
-2.0
```

Comment: Which sacrifices cross-platform functionality for something that can easily be implemented in pure Python.

Comment: On the other hand, it has the virtues of computing the cube root (instead of the 0.33333333333333331482961625624739099...rd power, which is why the OP ran into the problem to start with), and being both more accurate and faster on some platforms.  If you don't need portability, this can be a very practical solution.

Answer (score 3):

The cubic root of a negative number is just the negative of the cubic root of the absolute value of that number.

i.e. x^(1/3) for x < 0 is the same as (-1)*(|x|)^(1/3)

Just make your number positive, and then perform cubic root.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` has [an inbuilt cube root function `cbrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html) that handles negative numbers fine:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.cbrt(-8)
-2.0
```

This was added in version `1.10.0` (released `2015-10-06`).

Also works for `numpy` `array` / `list` inputs:

```
>>> np.cbrt([-8, 27])
array([-2.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cbrt` from `scipy.special`:

```
>>> from scipy.special import cbrt
>>> cbrt(-3)
-1.4422495703074083
```

This also works for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

this works with numpy array as well:

```
cbrt = lambda n: n/abs(n)*abs(n)**(1./3)
```

Comment: why not `(abs(n)*n)*(abs(n)**(1./3))`? I tend to avoid division for performance reasons.

Comment: @Salixalba: Seriously? In Python, I doubt you'll see any significant performance difference between division and multiplication of floats.  (Also, your suggestion computes `n**2` times the cube root, not the cube root.)

Answer (score 1):

#### New in Python 3.11

There is now [**`math.cbrt`**](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/math.html#math.cbrt) which handles negative roots seamlessly:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.cbrt(-3)
-1.4422495703074083
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive solution:

```
def cubic_root(nr):
   if nr<0:
     return -math.pow(-nr, float(1)/3)
   else:
     return math.pow(nr, float(1)/3)
```

Probably massively non-pythonic, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem and found the NumPy solution from [this forum post](http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/numpy-array-root-operation-td1727.html).

In a nushell, we can use of the NumPy `sign` and `absolute` methods to help us out. Here is an example that has worked for me:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-81,25])
print x
#>>> [-81  25]

xRoot5 = np.sign(x) * np.absolute(x)**(1.0/5.0)     
print xRoot5
#>>> [-2.40822469  1.90365394]

print xRoot5**5
#>>> [-81.  25.]
```

So going back to the original cube root problem:

```
import numpy as np

y = -3.
np.sign(y) * np.absolute(y)**(1./3.)
#>>> -1.4422495703074083
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For an arithmetic, calculator-like answer in Python 3:

```
>>> -3.0**(1/3)
-1.4422495703074083
```

or `-3.0**(1./3)` in Python 2.

For the algebraic solution of `x**3 + (0*x**2 + 0*x) + 3 = 0` use numpy:

```
>>> p = [1,0,0,3]
>>> numpy.roots(p)
[-3.0+0.j          1.5+2.59807621j  1.5-2.59807621j]
```