# Unexpected promotion to 'complex' type in Python math expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

While implementing a numerical optimization algorithm I came across some rather strange behavior in Python: after applying the [Six-hump cambel back function](http://www.geatbx.com/docu/fcnindex-01.html#P247_13252) on some values form the function's domain, some results evaluate to 'complex' numbers.

The code for evaluating a number is as simple as it can get:

```
def f(x1, x2):   
    return ((4 - 2.1 * x1 ** 2 + x1 ** (4 / 3)) * x1 ** 2 + x1 * x2 +
            (-4 + 4 * x2 ** 2) * x2 ** 2)
```

Here are some numbers for which the above function returns a complex number:

```
x1                    x2                   Result
-1.30423635697717    -1.750915750915751    27.13078459548355-2.099189473463638j
-0.28677817116347226  0.3413919413919415  -0.20277691810793963-0.013469483248785653j
-1.105725796606031   -0.5816849816849816   0.8001125335594826-1.2106597512385535j
```

And some numbers for which the above functions returns a normal float:

```
x1   x2  Result
1    2   52.9
1.4 -2   48.04232245707135
```

Why exactly is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

The code is run under Python 3.3.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `x1 ** (4 / 3)` is taking the variable `x1` to the power of `4/3`. When `x1` is negative, the [result of the expression has 3 roots; 2 of them are complex](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%5E%20%284/3%29). Python is choosing the "principal root" for you, which is complex in this case.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361740/cubic-root-of-the-negative-number-on-python) for ideas.

Comment: "Use math.pow(x1, 4/3) to get the real root of the variable" - this doesn't work and isn't the solution given at the link.

Comment: @Random832 yep, here's a different approach

Comment: Ahh..I missed that. The accepted answer from the link posted several edits ago works like a charm.

Comment: I'll put it back, then.