# I need a very precise number, but ipython is rounding it wrong

Tags: ipython

Basically, I have a constant called F

```
F=-5.9341737921479211e-05
```

and I need to get the cubic root of this constant. But when I try to do either

```
F**(1/3)
```

or

```
np.power(F,(1/3))
```

I always get the result F=1.0, which is completely wrong. The correct result is approximately -0.039. How can I get a precise value instead of this completely wrong result?

It seems to be something basic, but I have no idea why it's happening and I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Do you know what `1/3` is in the version of Python you're using?

Comment: In Python 2.7, '/' does Integer division. Probably this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3

Comment: 0.333... ? Isn't it?

Comment: It works as expected in Python3

Comment: Don't guess - type `1/3` into a Python shell and see what you get.  In Python 2, you'll get `0`.  Then try, e.g., `1.0/3` instead.

Comment: In python 2.x, you could also write F**(1.0/3.0)

Comment: You are using python 2 do this: `-abs(F)**(1.0/3)`

Comment: You have a minus sign in your post.  I don't believe you want it there.  Without it, your equations works with python 3 an python 2.7 (using @Supahupe's formula

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is a negative number and the answer would be slightly different than the duplicate.

Comment: @Kasramvd if they're getting `1.0`, it's an integer division problem. Solving that they may see other problems, but they can solve those too!

Comment: I am using ipython, and when I type, for example:
    1/3
it returns to me 0.333333333.
I tried all the methods you guys said on the comments, but nothing is working

Comment: Usingthe library from __future__ import division, I could make the constant F work. But now another constant G=-0.043983285322792547 when I try to get the cubic root, I just receive the result "nan"

Comment: I could make it working following this response:
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361750/6519480