# Wrong value for cube root in Python

Tags: python, math

Using Python 3.5 both at [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) and the console in Windows, I get wrong answers for cube roots.

When the input is `(-1)**(1/3)`,
I get the complex number (0.5000000000000001+0.8660254037844386j) as the answer when it should simply be -1. Any negative value under this root seems to give a complex result.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why should it be -1?

Comment: [You are getting the correct answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8760/what-are-the-three-cube-roots-of-1), but it's only one of 3 possible answers.

Comment: @omri_saadon why it should not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Python doesn't know that you are taking a cube root !

All it sees is a floating-point argument with a value close to 0.3333333333..., but due to the finiteness of the representation, it is impossible to guess that you mean exactly 1/3.

So all that Python can do is fall back on the usual definition of the exponentiation of negative bases to a real power (main branch), via the formula

```
(-x)^y = exp(y(ln(x) + iπ) = exp(y ln(x)) (cos(yπ) + i sin(yπ))
```

which yields a complex value.

Answer (score 2):

Exponentiation with negative bases typically involves complex numbers, so Python switches to complex numbers when it sees the negative base. Such exponentiation is typically mutlivalued, and Python doesn't always return the value you might expect.

For the special case of the 1/3 power with real bases, you could write a function like this:

```
def cubeRoot(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x**(1/3)
    else:
        return -(-x)**(1/3)
```

Which will give the expected real cube root.

Comment: After looking into this more, I seem to be unable to find a method that gives you back all 3 in this case, just the ability to force the real number as you do in this answer. Do you know if such a method exists?

Comment: For example, I tried two methods from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361740/cubic-root-of-the-negative-number-on-python/1362288) and the real root is being reported as `-1+1.2246467991473532e-16j`. This is just for my own curiosity, not requested by OP.

Comment: 1/3 is not representable as a floating point number, and so there's many more than 3 values of (-1)**x where x is the closest floating point number to 1/3.

Comment: @PaulHankin I understand the floating point restriction but in this particular case there is one real root. But even that is being reported back with an imaginary component (albeit very small) from the ones I've tried.

Comment: @roganjosh Good question. Don't know off the top of my head. Probably something in `sympy` would work such as `sympy.roots`

Comment: Thank you! Real roots is what I was looking for. Kind of weird to default to the complex answer.

Comment: To avoid a second sign test, return `-(-x)**(1/3)`.

Comment: @Lupilum Not really that weird. As a floating point number `1/3` can't really be distinguished from numbers like `100000000001/300000000000` where the even denominator rules out real solutions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that would work for negative `x` but fail for positive. Unless you know ahead of time if `x` is negative you have to test. I could of course have returned `x**(1/3) if x >= 0 else -(-x)**(1/3)` to make it shorter, but I wanted to spell out the logic more explicitly.

Comment: @JohnColeman: that's what I mean, there is no need to test the sign twice. I don't think that `abs(x)` is clearer than `-x`, it breaks symmetry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see what you mean. Good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get exactly this answer because the power operator computes

```
x**y = exp(y*ln(x))
```

and if `x` is not a positive real then its logarithm is computed from the main branch of the complex logarithm

```
ln(u+i*v)=0.5*ln(u²+v²) + i*arg(u+i*v)
```

where in math library terms `arg(u+i*v)=atan2(v,u)`.

Thus `ln(-1)=i*pi` and

```
(-1)**(1.0/3)=exp(i*pi/3)=cos(pi/3)+i*sin(pi/3)
```

which has the value that you got. Floating point errors occur since `y=1.0/3` is not exactly `1/3`, `pi` is not exactly the mathematical constant of the same name and the trigonometric functions are also approximations to the exact mathematical functions.