# Unable to replicate Excel fractional power logic in Python

Tags: python, excel

I am working on a problem where I need to recalculate Excel formulas in python and have come across some inconsistencies in how fractional powers are handled.

**Formula 1: (-6)^(1/3)**

In Excel the answer is `-1.8712`

In python, I get a complex number as expected. But I can reverse-engineer how Excel does it by removing removing the negative and computing as follows
`-1*operator.pow(6,1/3)`

**Formula 1: (-2.87)^(1/6)**

In Excel the answer is a NUM error.

In python, if I follow the same rule as above i.e. `-1*operator.pow(2.87,1/6)`, I get `-1.192` as the answer

How can I go about reconciling this? Is my algorithm wrong here?

Comment: If my answer helped you you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: (gray checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

`(-2.87)^(1/6)` is a complex number (I assume).

Now, your way of doing it gives `-(2.87^(1/6))`, which is real, as you *can* take the sixth root of `2.87`.

It's just a matter of parentheses.

Also in the third root, you can take the negative out just fine, because `(-1)^(1/3) = -1`. However, you can't take the negative out for the square root, as the square root of `-1` is complex. Since `1/6 = 1/2 * 1/3`, you can't take the negative for the sixth root.

Comment: Parentheses bite again :-)

Comment: Sorry I'm even more confused now. So both these formulas result in complex numbers. But for Formula 1, Excel is able to remove the -1 separately for computation, but is not able to do that for Formula 2. Why is that? Does the order of operations change between Formula 1 and Formula 2?

Comment: @BigBen I should have been clearer with the parentheses. Formula 1 is (-6)^(1/3), which results in a complex number in python

Comment: @Anubhav - and formula two's parentheses are?

Comment: @BigBen Just updated my comment. Formula 1 is (-6)^(1/3) and Formula 2 is (-2.87)^(1/6)

Comment: @Anubhav - both versions of Formula 1, with and without parentheses around `-6`, are equivalent. Excel takes the cubed root of `-6`, *not* `-1` times the cubed root of `6`. This has everything to do with parentheses and nothing to do with the order of operations.

Comment: @BigBen. That's what I thought. But the answer is a complex function. If you try this in python:  `a = -6`; `b= 1/3`; `c= a**b`; `print(c)`. The answer is `(0.9085602964160701+1.5736725951324722j)` which is complex.

Comment: @Anubhav - [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189413/wrong-value-for-cube-root-in-python); perhaps even a duplicate.

Comment: @Anubhav Python does not take the *principal* root, instead it takes one of the two complex roots of ``x^3 + 6 = 0``.

Comment: @Anubhav I haven't seen you in a while?