# Calculating CAGR by row by row in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, foreach

I am working with company data. I have a data set of round about 1900 companies (index) and 30 variables per company (columns). These varibales always come in pairs of three (three periods). It basically looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                       'revenue_0' : [7,2,5,4],
                       'revenue_1' : [5,6,3,1],
                       'revenue_2' : [1,9,4,8],
                       'profit_0' : [3,6,4,4],
                       'profit_1' : [4,6,9,1],
                       'profit_2' : [5,5,9,8]})
```

I am trying to compute the [compound annual growth rate (CAGR)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp?layout=infini&v=5A&adtest=5A&ato=3000&lgl=rira-baseline-vertical) for e.g. `revenue` for each company (`id`) - such that `revenue_cagr = ((revenue_2/revenue_1)^(1/3))-1`

I would like to pass a function to a set of columns row by row - at least, that is my idea.

```
def CAGR(start_value, end_value, periods): 
    ((end_value/start_value)^(1/periods))-1
```

Is it possible to apply this function row by row for a set of columns (maybe with `for i, row in df.iterrows():` or `df.apply()`)? Respectively, is there a smarter way to do this?

#### Update

The desired outcome - examplified with the column `revenue_cagr` - should look as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                           'revenue_0' : [7,2,5,4],
                           'revenue_1' : [5,6,3,1],
                           'revenue_2' : [1,9,4,8],
                           'profit_0' : [3,6,4,4],
                           'profit_1' : [4,6,9,1],
                           'profit_2' : [5,5,9,8],
                           'revenue_cagr' : [-0.48, 0.65, -0.07, 0.26],
                           'profit_cagr' : [0.19, -0.06, 0.31, 0.26]
                  })
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, the desired output is are columns with the CAGRs. I upates the question accordingly. I would like to have a column with the row-by-row cagr for the revenue columns and another column for the profits etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `triples` first:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1)   
print (df1)
   profit       revenue      
        0  1  2       0  1  2
id                           
1       3  4  5       7  5  1
2       6  6  5       2  6  9
3       4  9  9       5  3  4
7       4  1  8       4  1  8
```

Then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) all `2` with `0` levels selected by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), add [`pow`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html), [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df1 = df1.xs('2', axis=1, level=1)
         .div(df1.xs('0', axis=1, level=1))
         .pow((1./3))
         .sub(1)
         .add_suffix('_cagr')
print (df1)
    profit_cagr  revenue_cagr
id                           
1      0.185631     -0.477242
2     -0.058964      0.650964
3      0.310371     -0.071682
7      0.259921      0.259921
```

Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(df1, on='id')
print (df)
  id  profit_0  profit_1  profit_2  revenue_0  revenue_1  revenue_2  \
0  1         3         4         5          7          5          1   
1  2         6         6         5          2          6          9   
2  3         4         9         9          5          3          4   
3  7         4         1         8          4          1          8   

   profit_cagr  revenue_cagr  
0     0.185631     -0.477242  
1    -0.058964      0.650964  
2     0.310371     -0.071682  
3     0.259921      0.259921
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, this is a super cool solution. Especially, since it introduces me to a concept I was unaware of: `expand`. However, it does not work in my case. I have columns names with serveral underscores. Such as `profit_margin_0` or `revenue_per_month_0`. I don't mind calling the columns one by one - even if its more work than your cool solution. Is there any other way?

Comment: If only this problem you can use `rsplit` with `n=1` it split by last `underscore`. Is it possible?

Comment: Great solution! One last thing: the initial data frame `df` has many columns next to the `id` that do not have underscores such aus `city` and others. If I set the indext by using `df1 = df.set_index('id')` I can't join the data frames in the end. I get the error `columns overlap but no suffix specified`. Is there a way to circumvent that? Maybe to keep `id` in both dataframe and merge/join based on `id`?

Comment: Then you can simplify solution. Instead `df1 = df.set_index('id')` use `df1 = df.copy()` and instead `df = df.join(df1, on='id')` use `df = df.join(df1)`

Comment: I have one more question: Your solutions works beautifully, as long as the starting values aren't negative. Unfortunately, `python` does not seem to cope well with cubic roots of negative values (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361740/cubic-root-of-the-negative-number-on-python).

Unfortunately, I get quite a few np.nan/missings because of this issue. Any ideas how to circumenvent that?

Comment: Unfortunately now I am offline (only on phone), so better is post new question or I try find solution tomorrow. Sorry.