# Python exponent operator with fractional exponents

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python as a simple algebraic calculator, solving polynomials and such of a single variable. I'm seeing unexpected results when I use the `**` operator with fractional exponents. Specifically, it's producing complex numbers for values that should not be complex:

```
>>> (-1)**(1/3)
(0.5000000000000001+0.8660254037844386j)
```

The cube root of -1, of course, has a real number root at -1, which is what I would expect to come back.

What's the right way to raise values to arbitrary rational powers to avoid this problem? (If the builtin operator can't do this due to rounding or whatever, I'm open to using a library.)

Comment: There are three cube roots of -1,  and that's one of them.

Comment: good point, but if the input is a real number, I'd expect the output to be the real root. Jumping to complex numbers seems unexpected here. Is there a way to force it to stay in the real numbers?

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361740/cubic-root-of-the-negative-number-on-python

Comment: Whenever *x* is a real negative number, a real and negative *n*th root exists if and only if *n* is an odd integer

Comment: In the normal realm, under C99, `x**y` where `x` is negative and `y` is not an integer is undefined.

Comment: In Python 2, `1/3 == 0`. If this is Python3, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it is, fixed.

Comment: @Jerr hrm. the duplicate question is basically mine, but the answer look rather unwieldy for what I'm trying to do. If there isn't any other way to do it I'll close this as a dupe.

Comment: The implementation of `x ** y` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4048

Comment: You expect that, but there is no reason for a consistent  function to follow your expectation.  Indeed,  $1/3$ is a float so that the exact answer does not even have any root on the real line. Now you might say you want the solution closest to the real line, but that's very arbitrary and much less intuitive than just returning the first root in anticlockwise ordering of the complex plane

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use Python as a simple algebraic calculator, solving polynomials and such of a single variable.

One approach would be to use NumPy. Specifically, use [`np.roots()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) and extract the real results, if any:

```
>>> np.roots([1, 0, 0, 1])
array([-1.0+0.j       ,  0.5+0.8660254j,  0.5-0.8660254j])
```

Note that `[1, 0, 0, 1]` encodes the polynomial *x<sup>3</sup>+1*, the roots of which are precisely the cube root of -1.

Comment: this is a possibility, but I'm trying to encode things like, e.g. `x^2/3+6*x^2-11*x` as a python function, not just polynomials. I don't think `np.roots` can do that?