# Cube roots of a complex number in python

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers

How do I calculate the cube roots of a complex number in python? Currently, the only way I've found to do it is according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362288/7626856) answer, but I'm trying to remove any and all `import` statements from my code.

---

Current method, reproduced here:

```py
import math
def cuberoot( z ):
    z = complex(z) 
    x = z.real
    y = z.imag
    mag = abs(z)
    arg = math.atan2(y,x)
    resMag = mag**(1./3)
    resArg = [ (arg+2*math.pi*n)/3. for n in range(1,4) ]
    return [  resMag*(math.cos(a) + math.sin(a)*1j) for a in resArg ]
```

Comment: This sounds more like a math problem than programming. Once you find out the formula for calculating cube roots without using any functions, just code it in Python. [math.se] would be a more appropriate place to ask about the formula.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem That's presumably why he's returning a list of 3 numbers.

Comment: How do you want to pass your complex numbers to your function without importing the `math` or `cmath` module?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes, that's why there is a list returned

Comment: @Barmar, this is a coding problem. I understand how to calculate the roots. I'm now trying to do it without importing any libraries.

Comment: @lutre69 using `complex(n)`. No need for `cmath`.

Comment: @Clemson So you're asking how to calculate ATAN without using `math.atan()`? That's a math problem.

Comment: `math = __import__('math')`...now you don't have any import *statements* :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute one and multiply with the cube roots of 1?

```
cuberoots_of_1 = 1, complex(-.5, .75**.5), complex(-.5, -.75**.5)

def cuberoot(z):
    cuberoot = complex(z)**(1/3)
    return [cuberoot * cr1 for cr1 in cuberoots_of_1]
```

Test:

```
>>> cuberoot(-2 + 3j)
[(1.1532283040274223+1.0106429470939737j),
 (-1.4518566183526649+0.49340353410400484j),
 (0.2986283143252425-1.5040464811979786j)]

>>> for z in cuberoot(-2 + 3j):
        print(z**3, abs(z**3 - (-2 + 3j)))

(-1.999999999999999+3j) 1.1102230246251565e-15
(-1.999999999999999+3j) 1.1102230246251565e-15
(-1.9999999999999982+2.9999999999999996j) 1.831026719408895e-15
```

Doing the same with yours is less accurate:

```
(-1.999999999999996+3.000000000000002j) 4.572178254219406e-15
(-1.9999999999999933+3.000000000000004j) 7.768388458966724e-15
(-1.9999999999999956+3.0000000000000013j) 4.636427468134552e-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using rotation by a factor of `i^(2/3)`.

```
f = 1j**(2/3)
def cube_roots(z):
  r = z**(1/3)
  return [r, -r*f, r*f**2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in `complex` can handle finding one root out of the box:

```
def cube_root(v):
    if not isinstance(v, complex):
        v = complex(v, 0)
    return v ** (1.0 / 3.0)
```

Examples:

```
cube_root(-3)
(0.7211247851537043+1.2490247664834064j)

cube_root(complex(1, -2))
(1.2196165079717578-0.47171126778938893j)
```

The function you reproduced above is one way to get all three roots.

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361740/cubic-root-of-the-negative-number-on-python) response.

Comment: @Clemson note that the answer explicitly casts `v` as complex, so the issue from the link does not apply.