# How can I prevent the result from being a complex number? (Cube root of -27)

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers, nth-root

I've figured out the following solution (probably not that hard anyway):

```
n1, n2 = -27, 3
root = ( n1 ** (1/n2))
print(root)
```

> `(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)`

Unless I'm making a very dumb mistake, it should print -3 instead.

Comment: Related: [Cubic root of the negative number on python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361740/3890632).

Comment: one of strangest things I have seen in Python so far, when you do `-27 ** (1/3)` result is correct

Comment: @dankal444 That's because you're doing the equivalent of `-(27**(1/3))`.

Comment: Ah, of course.. my bad

Comment: In general, there are 3 solutions to `z**(1/3)` for some complex number `z`. Python returns only one of them.

Comment: This has to do with mathematics of complex numbers. There are three possible roots, one is -3 but the other two are complex. Python just returns the first root it finds. See this link for all 3 roots: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-27%29%5E%281%2F3%29

Comment: The easiest way would be to get the cube root of positive 27, and negate the result.

Comment: @khelwood, that actually works, thank you very much!

Comment: I still don't get why that happens though

Comment: @FishyBusinessYT it happens because Python computes the _ principal cube root_ of a number, and there are mathematical reasons to prefer that over the other two roots.

Comment: It's not the "first root it finds", but it's the _principal_ root, which is well-defined mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the real cubic root of a negative number, use:

```
number = -27
if number > 0:
    real_root = number ** (1/3)
elif number < 0:
    real_root = - (abs(number) ** (1/3))
elif number == 0:
    real_root = 0
```